# puppet cert list all using api/python?

Tags: python, puppet

I need to get the list of all puppet nodes (basically output of puppet cert list --all). What is the best way to do the same using python (without using exec or similar things on the command itself) in puppet 2.6.18

puppet 2.7.0 onwards has HTTP API to achieve the same.

http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/rest_api.html#certificate-request

GET /{environment}/certificate_statuses/no_key

puppetdb also one api but am not sure if the env am working with has puppetdb. (checking on that).

Is there anything like ansible.runner for puppet?
Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to [configure access to the REST API](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/rest_auth_conf.html) in `auth.conf`. Then you can use the built-in urllib2 or external requests library to query the API with the appropriate SSL client certificate for authentication.

If you don't want to deal with SSL client certificates, you can use `allow_ip` in `auth.conf`. I'd only do that if you're not interested in the more sensitive areas of the API (like requesting a catalog).

I wrote a Python wrapper around the Puppet REST API and posted it on GitHub: [pypuppet](https://github.com/daradib/pypuppet).

For example,

```
>>> import puppet
>>> p = puppet.Puppet()
>>> print p.certificates()
```

See the README and example `auth.conf` for more info. Let me know how it works out for you.

Comment: great, looks good. I dont control the environment in which puppet is deployed so can't really modify the auth.conf or use pypuppet. But will keep this in mind for future reference. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get the list of certificates without privileges on the puppet master. You can try looking at the contents of `/var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/signed` (replace `/var/lib/puppet` with whatever your `$vardir` is).